# Continue execution in console after running jar

Tags: java, jar, console

I have a jar that **executes endlessly** because i create a thread and the i join() the edt with this thread.
If i run this jar with double click on lets say windows a javaw process is created that runs forever and i can **continue working** which is what i want.
Now if i try to run the jar from cmd with java -jar myJar.jar the execution halts right there.
What i want is to continue cmd execution after running the jar.

**Note:**I currently trying to do this in linux console which i access with putty.So please consider this in your answer

Thank you

Comment: .. looking at the answers below - you're still on MS Windows, aren't you?

Comment: @Andreas_D: See the note in the question: This is about running Java on Linux (via putty).

Comment: @sleske - got it. pretty confusing - he's talking about windows, javaw, cmd and in a sidnote he finally reveals that now he's starting the application via rsh/ssh on a linux box... yikes.

Comment: @Andreas_D: Yes, the question could be more precise. But hey, he's only at 409 rep, he'll learn ;-).

Comment: @Andreas_D & @sleske I try to make this question generic so i can get a generic answer so i won't just solve the exact problem i have but learn how to react in this situation in every system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> java -jar myJar.jar &

The `&` puts the command into the background and allows you to do other things from the shell prompt.

This is very basic UNIX/Linux shell stuff.  I suggest that you find / read an online tutorial or a book on the shell you are using (e.g. bash).  It will make your life a lot easier.  Or if you are a masochist, read `man bash`.

> I currently trying to do this in linux console which i access with putty.

Use of putty is actually not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
java -jar myJar.jar&
```

It means that the process gets launched and runs in the background. If you want to get it back, type `fg`. To push it back in the background, press CTRL+Z (this pauses its execution and gives you back your shell prompt) and then run `bg` to resume it in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Just run it as

```
java -jar myJar.jar &
```

The `&` will put the command into the background, where it happily runs. Just a basic Unix shell feature.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer using screen. Because you can even define a session ID and restore them really easy.

You can start the jar with the following command:

```
screen -m -d java -jar myJar.jar
```

With the following command you can list all current sessions:

```
screen -ls
```

You can reopen a session with:

```
screen -r PID/Sessionname
```

Answer (score 0):

Undeleted this answer after the OP last comment - it's not an answer to the written question but an additional answer to his actual problem

---

On windows, try

```
start java -jar myJar.jar
```

Reference: [MS-DOS start command](http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm)